# How to enter object literal into JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript

... in string form.

I tried what I believed was the obvious.

[image]

Comment: JSON requires double quotes. Your single quote isn't valid JSON.

Comment: See: [Json.org](http://www.json.org/). You can also paste your string [here](http://jsonlint.com/) to see if it's valid.

Comment: Using `JSON.parse()`: http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/json/parse

Answer (score 7):

Double quotes are the [standard](http://www.json.org/) for JSON, not single quotes:

```
JSON.parse('{"a":"b"}')
```